# Laravel Model wrong return

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have this function in one of my controllers:

```
public function getApplicationFiles(Contract $contract) {
    dd($contract->get());
}
```

The parameter is defind in the url. So my route is

```
Route::get('contracts/files/{contract}', 'ContractController@getApplicationFiles');
```

My problem is that the function `getApplicationFiles` displays all entries from the `Contract` type and not only the Object with the given id?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use it like this: `dd($contract);`

Comment: So I get the QueryBuilder object: https://imgur.com/a/ZodnUky

Comment: That's not a query builder object but the correct model that you need. Try accessing a property on the object and you'll see. 
`$contract->id`, should give you what you want.

Comment: If i try something like `$contract->id` or `$contract->created_at` I get `null`. A database entrie with the id given in my url exists.

Comment: Double check the used namespace to make sure you haven't accidentally referenced a different Contract model?

Comment: Your screenshot shows an contract model object but it seems to be completely empty. It seems rather odd. Make sure you did not accidentally register the `Contract`  class to your dependency injection container to allow Laravel's model binding to take over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the following, make your route a named route like this:

```
Route::get('contracts/files/{contract}', 'ContractController@getApplicationFiles')->name('contract.files');
```

Then in your view use it like this:

```
<a href="{{route('contract.files', $contract)}}">Files</a>
```

This should give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

u don't need to pass all row u need to pass only one row try like this(**if you are paassing only contract id in request**)

```
public function getApplicationFiles(Contract $contract) {
    //dd($contract);
    return response()->json($contract);   // if you pass json
    return view('show',compact($contract); /// if you view 
}
```